# Limit Git command output by page

Tags: git

Is there a way to tell git to show the output by page and limit to X amount of results per page? If so, how does it work and how do you move to prev or next page?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GIT output uses `less` and, by default, your `LESS` environment variable options.  You can configure GIT to use your preferred `less` options with:

```
git config --global core.pager 'less -FRSX'
```

You move between pages using `less` keys (see `man less`).  The key 'b' is for backward one page; key 'f' or 'space' is for forward one page.

Answer (score 3):

Some git commands such as `log` and `diff` already use a pager by default. `status` has a `-p` key to use it too. To learn how to use a specific pager you need to read the documentation for that pager (such as `less` on Linux).

Comment: Thank you. Any links on where to find this documentation?

Comment: @IIS7Rewrite depends on the pager used.

Comment: I"m using git bash on windows. So anything that I can use with that will work.